# Is there a way I can successfully convert this python code into javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests

```py
import requests

def aqi_checker(city_name):
    api_key = "API_KEY"
    url = f"https://api.waqi.info/feed/{city_name}/?token={api_key}"
    
    response = requests.get(url)
    json_data = response.json()
    aqi = json_data['data']['aqi']
    return f"The AQI in {city_name} is {aqi}"


print(aqi_checker("new york city"))
```

Comment: Woah, don't post your API key or any other secret credentials in a StackOverflow question. If others get a hold of it, then they could get access to any accounts you may have.

Comment: it'd best to change or rotate your API key if possible, asap. otherwise, your code looks pretty solid to me. I like the way that you thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function aqi_checker(city_name) {
  let api_key = "API_KEY";
  let url = `https://api.waqi.info/feed/${city_name}/?token=${api_key}`;

  let response = fetch(url);
  let json_data = JSON.parse(response);
  let aqi = json_data["data"]["aqi"];
  return `The AQI in ${city_name} is ${aqi}`;
}

print(aqi_checker("new york city"));
```